# Local Angular server and Local node server not working for external devices

Tags: node.js, angular, localhost, localserver

I'm developing my MEAN application fully locally (Angular frontend and Node Backend). To test this I'm using my mobile with angular command ng serve --host  command. When I run my application data from the local node server not loading to mobile but it works with the Laptop browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do following steps:

(1) Ensure that your local machine and mobile phone are on same WiFi network.
(2) Get your local machine IP Address. It will be something like e.g. 184.192.108.xx
(3) Run angular application with command `ng serve --host 184.192.108.xx`

You can specify the `--port` and `--live-reload` options.

https://angular.io/cli/serve

Thanks!

Comment: Already did it. but the problem is the local backend. Backend is fully local and can the mobile load resources from the local backend?